# custom join query to get record from 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 3 table in mysql database like following

**table 1 : videos**

```
id    name
1     one
2     two
3     three
```

**table 2: tags**

```
id    name
1     stage=test
2     age=under18
```

**table 3 : tags_to_items** where `tags_id` = `tags.id` and `item_id`=`videos.id`

```
tag_id    item_id
1         1
2         2
2         1
1         3
```

Here `item_id 1` has 2 tags.
I want to select all the records from `videos` table where `tag_id=1` and `tag_id=2`. So output should be `video.id=1`.

Please help me to do like that, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need any query from videos or join. Just do what you need so far:

```
SELECT item_id as VIDEO_ID 
   SUM(CASE WHEN tag_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tag_1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN tag_id = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as tag_2
FROM tags_to items
WHERE tag_id = 1 or tag_id = 2
GROUP BY VIDEO_ID
HAVING tag_1>0 AND tag_2>0
```

Comment: i want all data from video table, so i think need join also to get name of video based on item_id

Comment: if you need more than `id` fix your question and write all your requirements together please

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id IN (SELECT item_id FROM tags_to_items WHERE tag_id IN (1,2) )
```

Comment: this will not work, in case sample data provided it will return all 3 rows

Comment: if this is what you posted as requirement **i want to select all the records from videos table where tag_id=1 and tag_id=2 **. Then, the above query will 100% work.

Comment: exactly he wrote **AND** so only **id=1** has both records

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
            SELECT t1.tag_id, t1.item_id, t2.name AS tagName, t3.name AS videoName FROM tags_to_items AS t1

            LEFT JOIN tags AS t2 ON t1.tag_id=t2.id

            LEFT JOIN videos AS t3 ON t1.item_id=t3.id

            WHERE t1.tag_id IN (1,2)
```